# why zinc can't move electrons to copper directly without any solution?

Tags: electrochemistry

We need an electric solution for the electrons to move from the anode to the cathode but why ?

Answer (score 1):

You need the solution to move the cations around and maintain local equilibrium for a sustained current in a closed current loop, otherwise you just get an initial current pulse to equilibrate the charge. But two metals create a potential difference on their own, due to different fermi levels / work function.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Volta_potential